# Implementing pixel-perfect collision - Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I just started learning game programming through the libgdx framework and I am at the collision detection stage of development. I made a pretty simple game that has some basic bounding-box collision detection system. However, I want to implement **pixel-perfect collision** for accuracy.

I will be showing snippets of code that I think are important to help you understand what is going on.

A two-dimensional array is created to define the position of the tiles on the screen:

```
int[][] map = {
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    };
```

This `create()` method from my main game class adds a player and three entities to an `ArrayList` of type `Entity`.

```
  @Override
  public void create () {
      batch = new SpriteBatch();
      tileTexture = new Texture("block.png");  
      screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
      screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

      // add some entities including a player
      entities.add(new Player(this, 100, 150, 20, 20, 120.0f, new Texture("player.png")));
      entities.add(new Entity(this, 50, 150, 20, 20, 120.0f, new Texture("enemy.png")));
      entities.add(new Entity(this, 200, 200, 20, 20, 120.0f, new Texture("enemy.png")));
      entities.add(new Entity(this, 180, 50, 20, 20, 120.0f, new Texture("enemy.png")));
  }
```

The `render() method` draws the tile map and the entities when the game is run. Another class named `Entity` holds the data of a particular entity (can be a block/player). The data can be the `x` and `y` position of that entity.

```
      // draw tile map
      // go over each row bottom to top
      for(int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
          // go over each column left to right      
          for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
              // tile
              if(map[x][y] == 1) {
                  batch.draw(tileTexture, x * tileSize, y * tileSize);
              }
          }
      }

      // draw all entities
      for(int i = entities.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          Entity e = entities.get(i);
          batch.draw(e.texture, e.x, e.y);
      }
```

This produces:
[image: Game screen when started]

To check for collision when the player (green block) moves, I have two methods that check if the player is colliding with an entity or a tile.

The `tileCollision()` method:

```
  public boolean tileCollision(Entity e, Direction direction, float newX, float newY) {
      boolean collision = false;

      // determine affected tiles
      int x1 = (int) Math.floor(Math.min(e.x, newX) / tileSize);
      int y1 = (int) Math.floor(Math.min(e.y, newY) / tileSize);
      int x2 = (int) Math.floor((Math.max(e.x, newX) + e.width - 0.1f) / tileSize);
      int y2 = (int) Math.floor((Math.max(e.y, newY) + e.height - 0.1f) / tileSize);

      // tile checks
      for(int x = x1; x <= x2; x++) {
          for(int y = y1; y <= y2; y++) {
              if(map[x][y] == 1) {
                  collision = true;
                  e.tileCollision(map[x][y], x, y, newX, newY, direction);
              }
          }
      }
      return collision;
  }
```

The line of code `e.tileCollision(map[x][y], x, y, newX, newY, direction);` in this method calls the `tileCollision()` method in the Entity class that prints the position of where the block collides with a tile.

To check collisions between entities, we have this method:

```
  public boolean entityCollision(Entity e1, Direction direction, float newX, float newY) {
      boolean collision = false;

      for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
          Entity e2 = entities.get(i);

          // we don't want to check for collisions between the same entity
          if(e1 != e2) {
              // axis aligned rectangle rectangle collision detection
              if(newX < e2.x + e2.width && e2.x < newX + e1.width &&
                  newY < e2.y + e2.height && e2.y < newY + e1.height) {
                  collision = true;

                  e1.entityCollision(e2, newX, newY, direction);
              }
          }
      }

      return collision;
  }
```

**NOTE:** The green block can move across an entity but cannot go through tiles. This is because the line `e1.entityCollision(e2, newX, newY, direction);` calls the `entityCollision()` method in the class `Entity` that lets the green block move.

This type of collision detection seems basic and inefficient (time complexity of `O(n^2)`).

How do I implement **pixel-perfect collision** in this context?

**Additional question:** If I want to improve the efficiency, what collision detection system can I use to eliminate unnecessary checks?